# How to create a two direction swip in a Flutter page?

Tags: flutter, swipe, horizontal-scrolling, gesturedetector, flutter-pageview

I am interested to know how can I make a `PageView` widget swipe able to both directions at the same time, like what we can see in the TikTok app that you can swipe videos vertically to change them, then also you can swipe to right or left to see the user's profile, etc.

What is the best way of implementing this?